# String concatenation in react props

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to react and trying to change the page title and I'm unable to do string concatenation using props.I tried using -, + etc.I don't get it.Can someone help.

document.title = this.props.messages.Title - this.props.messages.bookshelf;

Comment: Take a look at react-helmet, it provides a cleaner approach.

Comment: I'm newbie to react.Sure will take a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a template literal: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

```
document.title = `${this.props.messages.Title} - ${this.props.messages.bookshelf}`;
```